# Use UIPageViewController inside a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

Inside a `collectionViewCell` I want to create a view with dots on the bottom and where I can swipe between the views. Shall I use `UIPageController` to show the dots and implement the gesture recognition manually or is it possible to use `UIPageViewController` inside the `collectionViewCell`?

Comment: use the container view in collection view cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have it in your cell. It doesn't have to be full screen. In fact it can be used as any other UIViewController. If you want to embed it in a smaller rectangle, you can use UIViewController containment.

Let's assume that you want to embed it into a parent controller which is a UIViewController subclass. Then define a pageViewController property and add it as a child view controller in viewDidLoad:

```
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageViewController.view.frame = ... //set the frame or add autolayout constraints

[self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

In **swift**:

```
    let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    pageViewController.view.frame = view.frame//set frame
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Thank you for editing my snippet in swift! I had the code snipped in objective c and wasn't near my laptop (for xcode) to convert it to swift! If you don't mind I'll add this code to my answer. thanks again! :)

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani you can upvote for my swift solution so that other can get it in use.. Hapy coding :)